# MFMessageComposeViewController doesn't send out the message

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I'm trying to send out the message by MFMessageComposeViewController.
Delegate get the result MessageComposeResultSent. But I didn't receive the SMS in fact. And I can't find the history in Message.

This problem also occurs in Sample code provided by developer.apple.com
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Device: iPhone5S
OS: iOS 7.1.2

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-send-sms-text-message/  try like this,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks self-fixed when I reboot my iphone.
I totally have no idea about the reason, but it really works now.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
 NSArray *arrPhoneNumbers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1234567890", nil];
 MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.body = @"Message";
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arrPhoneNumbers];
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```